# get the second tds tag text in this html string

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the text in the second td tag in this html string, can I pass a html string into the JQUERY object and filter through it like this?

```
var t = '<td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>f</td>g<td>h</td>';


$(t).find("td:eq(1)").html();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.find` is for finding descendants in the current set, the set is actually the td elements themselves so you need to operate on that, for example by using the [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method:

```
var t = '<td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td><td>f</td>g<td>h</td>';
$(t).eq(1).html();
//"b"
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NxcUk/

---

```
var t = '<td>a</td><td><div>firstdiv</div><div>seconddiv</div></td><td>c</td><td>f</td>g<td>h</td>';
$(t).eq(1).find("div:first").html();
//"firstdiv"
```

Comment: thank you  - and if the second td had a div? is this right --> $(t).eq(1).find('div:first').html();